# how to pass data to another view laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

i have some data more that 1 in database. i want to pass the data when i clicked the button href and pass it to another view but only take the data than what i clicked. is there a way?

```html
@foreach ($data as $datas)
<div class="card">
  <img src={{$datas->gambar}} alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>{{$datas->judul}}</b></h4>
    <p>{{$datas->artis}}</p>
    <p>Stock = {{$datas->stok}}</p>
  </div>
  <a href="/details " class="button">Rental</a>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the `$data` id in the link like:

```
<a href="/details/{{ $data->id }}" class="button">Rental</a>
```

You'll then need a corresponding route that accepts `id` as a parameter:

```
Route::get('/details/{id}', 'DataController@show');
```

and of course the controller method implementation:

```
// DataController
public function show(Request $request, $id) {
    return view('data.show', ['single_data' => Data::find($id)]);
}
```

**update**

If you want to use a different field than `id` for the primary key, update your model accordingly:

```
class Data extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = 'judul';
}
```

Comment: is the id is the parameter like key that i have to catch when pass the data?

Comment: The `id` should be the primary key of the table which `$datas` is from.

Comment: what if i want the judul become a primary key?

Comment: You can use whichever attribute you want, `$data->judul`, just be sure to set the `$primaryKey` attribute in the model correctly and all should work.

Comment: what is Data in `Data::find($id)` means?

Comment: It means search the `Data` model for a record with the given `$id`

Comment: actually i'm new in laravel. so, am i have to make Data in Controller and extend model?. because i'm trying to put `class Data extends Model {
  protected $primaryKey = 'id';
}` in MainController because the `Data` not be found, but now the `Model` not be found

Answer (score 0):

```
// view    
@foreach ($data as $datas)
    <div class="card">
      <img src={{$datas->gambar}} alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
      <div class="container">
        <h4><b>{{$datas->judul}}</b></h4>
        <p>{{$datas->artis}}</p>
        <p>Stock = {{$datas->stok}}</p>
      </div>
      <a href="{{ route('details',$datas->your_value) }}" class="button">Rental</a>
    </div>

@endforeach

//route
Route::get('/details/{data}', ['uses'=>'YourController@your_func', 'as'=>'details']);

// Controller
public function your_func($data){
  return view('your_view')->with('data',$data);
}

//next view

{{ dd($data) }}
```

Comment: what is dd means? and why the bracket don't have close?

Comment: dd means "Dump and Die". It dumps the data in laravel. like print_r($var); die(); . and it must have closing bracket.